# How to extract *Area Code* from a phone number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL table with following for **Phone Number** column.

```
(201) 411-5200x4002
1 (5410) 651-8868 x 5
1-308-987-5920 x8031
2118477656
2195992321x289
313-877-5916
```

I need to extract out `Area Code` out of these phone numbers. Area code is first three digits of number. But if we have country code too (1 (5410) 651-8868) then it is quite difficult to find.

I'm using SQL Server 2012...

Please help.

Comment: Can you tell us what the correct results are for the 6 examples you've given please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function where you can pass your phone no and it will return you the area code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_GetAreaCode] 
(
    @phoneNumber as nvarchar(200)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @areaCodeAbbr as nvarchar(50)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    if Exists(select 1 from sys.tables where @phoneNumber like '1-%' or @phoneNumber like '1(%') or @phoneNumber like '1 %')
        set @phoneNumber = RIGHT(@phoneNumber,len(@phoneNumber)-2)

    set @phoneNumber = replace(@phoneNumber,'(','')
    set @phoneNumber = replace(@phoneNumber,')','')
    set @phoneNumber = replace(@phoneNumber,'-','')
    set @phoneNumber = LTRIM(@phoneNumber)

    SELECT 
        @areaCodeAbbr = left(@phoneNumber,3)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @areaCodeAbbr

END
```

To call the function write a sql like -

```
Select dbo.f_GetAreaCode('(201) 411-5200x4002')
```

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for! (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL, and no dbms specified in question...)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012 ..

Comment: This will not work for `1 (5410) 651-8868 x 5`, you should add this line too: `set @phoneNumber = replace(@phoneNumber,' ','')` to replace whitespaces.